# Confusing pandas Panel behavior : am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, panel

In [142]:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2,3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
d = {'name' : pd.Panel(items=['x', 'y', 'z'])}

d['name']['x']
```

Out[142]:

```
Index([], dtype='object')   Empty DataFrame
0 rows × 0 columns
```

This doesn't seem to work:

In [143]:

```
d['name']['x'] = df
d['name']['x']
```

Out[143]:

```
Index([], dtype='object')   Empty DataFrame
0 rows × 0 columns
```

But this does:

In [144]:

```
df1 = df
df1
```

Out[144]:

```
    a  b  c  d
0   0  1  2  3

1 rows × 4 columns
```

Is there something about Panels that I'm missing?

Comment: Is there a reason you're constructing it like that? It's possible that there's a bug there, but you probably don't want to be mutating the indexes of the Panel by setting `wp['x'] = df`. Presumably you don't have the data at the time of panel construction, but why not store a dict of DataFrames and convert to a panel when you're actually going to use it?

Comment: You're right that I can work around it, but I was just curious as to why it doesn't work.